# how to write into an empty json file?

Tags: python, json

I am a beginner learning to code in python. I am currently trying to learn json. I am working on a simple program that stores your favorite number.

This is the code:

```
import json

def get_new_favorite_number():
    favorite_number = input('please enter your favorite number')
    filename = 'favorite_number.json'
    with open(filename, 'w') as f_obj:
        json.dump(favorite_number, f_obj)

def get_favorite_number():
    filename = 'favorite_number.json'
    with open(filename) as f_obj:
        favorite_number = json.load(f_obj)
    return favorite_number

def tell_favorite_number():
    favorite_number = get_favorite_number()
    if favorite_number: 
        print('your favorite number is ' + str(favorite_number))
    else:
        favorite_number = get_new_favorite_number()


tell_favorite_number()
```

if I try to run the code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "favorite_number.py", line 23, in <module>
    tell_favorite_number()
  File "favorite_number.py", line 16, in tell_favorite_number
    favorite_number = get_favorite_number()
  File "favorite_number.py", line 12, in get_favorite_number
    favorite_number = json.load(f_obj)
  File "C:\Python\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Python\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
```

But if I enter a number in favoritenumber.json, for example 43 and then run the program again, the program runs successfully and I get this output:

```
your favorite number is 43
```

could you explain why this happens, and how to make the program runs successfully without needing a previous data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out `try except` blocks

```
import json

def get_new_favorite_number():
    favorite_number = input('please enter your favorite number')
    filename = 'favorite_number.json'
    with open(filename, 'w') as f_obj:
        json.dump(favorite_number, f_obj)

def get_favorite_number():
    filename = 'favorite_number.json'
    with open(filename) as f_obj:
        try:
            favorite_number = json.load(f_obj)
        except:
            favorite_number = None
    return favorite_number

def tell_favorite_number():
    favorite_number = get_favorite_number()
    if favorite_number is not None: 
        print('your favorite number is ' + str(favorite_number))
    else:
        favorite_number = get_new_favorite_number()
```

You get this error because the json library tries to decode a non exsistent value.

You can simply store your number in a text file, or handle the exception. In your `except` block you can call `get_new_favorite_number`.

With storing your value in a text file, you can easily edit it by hand.

Answer (score 1):

In the `tell_favorite_number()` try to replace

```
favorite_number = get_favorite_number()
```

with

```
try:
    favorite_number = get_favorite_number()
except:
    favorite_number = 0
```

Comment: Probably it's better to handle error of `json` library directly on call to it's function.